# ¿Por qué la longitud del array es undefined al meter los elementos en un .then()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, promesas

Tengo la siguiente petición con `axios`:

```
const requests = [...Array(nQuestions).keys()];
for (const elem of requests) {
  axios
  .get(`${baseURL}/pregunta/random`)
  .then(response => {
     const oldQuestions = questionsTest;
     const newQuestions = oldQuestions.push(response.data);
     setQuestionsTest(newQuestions);
     console.log('questionsTest: ' + questionsTest.length);
     console.log(questionsTest);
     if (questionsTest.length === nQuestions) {
       setTestState(1);
       console.log('all: ', questionsTest);
     }
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Todo eso está dentro de ese `for...of` para hacer la petición `nQuestion` veces y obtener un documento aleatorio de la base de datos.

A medida que se recorre el array `questionsTest` va tomando valores como se puede ver aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al llegar al final sale su longitud y su contenido es `undefined` ni siquiera `[]`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué ocurre esto y como obtengo los datos entonces?

Se supone que se están seteando cada vez que se reciben y por eso cada que termina uno de esos llamados que quedan en "segundo plano" obtengo la data...

¿Cuando se acaban esos llamados se pierde la referencia a los datos y por eso al final queda sin datos el arreglo (`questionsTest`)?

Comment: Lo que no me explico es porque los undefined están en la línea 245 y 249. Luego de la primera iteración también sale un undefined en la línea 245.  Ahora si no tuviera length en la última iteración porque questionsTest es undefined porque no se ejecuta el catch. Pero no es así. No creo que los mensajes se refieran a lo que indicas. Puedo ver las líneas 245 y 249.

Comment: Ya no lo tengo, pero las líneas 245 y 249 indican dos console.log() que se ejecutaban cuando setTestState(1) se ejecutaba. Esos logs estaban dentro de un useEffect(..., [testState]).

Comment: Ahorita mismo intenté otro enfoque pero en el fondo son lo mismo, lo curioso es que el método como consigo los datos si funciona en otro functional component...

Comment: Hola, es un problema de enfoque para ser mas claro un problema de sincronicidad, para hacerlo corto ese codigo tiene que ser reescrito usando llamadas asyncronas, con las ya conocidas async/await. 

Otra manera es como se menciona en este url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532652/axios-get-then-in-a-for-loop 

Espero que te sirva, Saludos

Comment: ¡Lo intentaré con async/await! Gracias.